# querySelectorAll does not work with pseudo class nth-last-child

Tags: javascript, html, css-selectors

I have this javascript code:

```
var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset:nth-last-child("-n+2")');
console.log('fieldsets' + fieldsets);
```

And I have 4 fieldsets

I get this error in the chrome inspector:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'fieldset:nth-last-child("-n+2")' is not a valid selector.
```

I hope someone can help!
Thanks :)!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the quotes  around the argument expression.

```
var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll('fieldset:nth-last-child(-n+2)');
```